# centralizar verticalmente row bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Precisava centralizar esta row no meio da pagina, seguindo a documentação do bootstrap, me diz para colocar `align-items-center` junto com row, eu fiz, porem não mudou nada. minha estrutura html atualmente esta assim:

```
<!-- linha dos card -->
            <div class="row align-items-center" >
                <!-- Tab cursos conteudo -->
                <div class="tab-content ">
                    <div class="tab-pane active container " id="ingles">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane container" id="teenkids">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane container" id="incompany">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane container" id="espanhol">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Isso tudo esta dentro de uma div container, alguma outra alternativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor a explicação pode parecer meio boba, mas quando vc ver o exemplo vai entender melhor.

O que está acontecendo é que para o elemento Filho ficar alinhado na vertical no meio do Pai o Pai precisa de uma altura definida!

O jeito que vc fez é o certo mesmo a `.ROW` já é `display:flex` por default e a class nativa `align-items-cente` significa `align-items:center` que também está certo, então não tem nada para corrigir, vc só precisa por uma altura definida na `.ROW` Pai, pois os seus Filhos já estão alinhados, vc só não percebe isso pq o Pai não tem um `height` maior que o dos filhos.

Para entende melhor veja o exemplo. Eu coloquei na `.ROW` uma altura de `100vh` que é a altura total de *ViewPort* e veja que os itens ficaram no meio da página! *(também usei a classe `justify-content-center` para alinha na horizontal)*

### OBS:

> Execute na *"Página toda"* para ver melhor o resultado!

```css
.row.red {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container">
    <!-- linha dos card -->
    <div class="row red align-items-center justify-content-center" >
            <!-- Tab cursos conteudo -->
            <div class="tab-content ">
                <div class="tab-pane active container " id="ingles">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane container" id="teenkids">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane container" id="incompany">

                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane container" id="espanhol">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Link oficial da Documentação Flex do Bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, alterei toda estrutura do html pois tinha mais elementos alem dos cards, e ficou do jeito que queria

Comment: @IgorOliveira legal jovem que bom que de certo ai. Tem bastante material sobre FlexBox pela internet, depois da uma olhada pq vale muita a pena e já é bem aceito pelos Browsers etc. Tmj

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `transform`, mas é preciso também que o `body` tenha a altura do *viewport*. Pode usar uma classe própria (coloquei `.align_vertical`).

Execute o exemplo abaixo em **tela cheia** para visualizar o efeito:

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
.align_vertical{
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- linha dos card -->
<div class="row align_vertical" >
    <!-- Tab cursos conteudo -->
    <div class="tab-content ">
        <div class="tab-pane active container " id="ingles">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane container" id="teenkids">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane container" id="incompany">

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane container" id="espanhol">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```